# Is comma optional in "Heating the limestone (calcium carbonate) drives off carbon dioxide gas [comma] leaving behind lime, the base calcium oxide"?

Tags: punctuation, commas

From a PDF containing teacher's notes on teaching limestone chemistry:

> Heating the limestone (calcium carbonate) drives off carbon dioxide gas leaving behind lime, the base calcium oxide.

Do we need a comma before "leaving behind lime", or is it optional? Maybe the presence of "the base calcium oxide" makes it awkward to use a second comma in the sentence?

I'm not against the comma before "the base", I'm wondering whether we should use a comma before "leaving", like this:

> Heating the limestone (calcium carbonate) drives off carbon dioxide gas,  leaving behind lime, the base calcium oxide.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The comma before *leaving* is desirable: it reflects the required spoken "reading" the sentence would take.

Without the comma, the participle phrase *leaving behind lime &c* is taken to be a restrictive modifier on *gas*, as if *gas* were the subject of *leave*; this would be equivalent to *the carbon dioxide gas which leaves behind lime*. In speech this meaning would be realized as a continuous phrase, with even stresses: 'gas 'leaving be'hind 'lime. . .

It's pretty clear, however, that *leaving behind lime* is a clausal modifier,  that the subject of *leave* is the entire preceding clause: what leaves lime behind is the action of driving off the gas. In speech this distinction is realized with what is loosely called a "pause"—actually a lengthened syllable with a falling intonation— on *gas*, followed by a new phrase starting with *leaving*. That "pause" is what the comma represents.

Answer (score 1):

As written, the comma is needed, because "the base calcium oxide" defines "lime". If you read it as:

> ...lime the base calcium oxide.

it doesn't make any sense.

I think this was written strangely though, in that after defining limestone in parenthesis is the first phrase, lime was defined in a separate clause in the second phrase. I would prefer:

> Heating the limestone (calcium carbonate) drives off carbon dioxide gas, leaving behind lime (the base calcium oxide).

Comment: "lime the base calcium oxide" - I was not having in mind that comma, I was talking of the comma before "leaving".

Comment: I would leave it in as it divides two separate actions. As I would say this sentence, I put a natural pause there.